# Use WC_Order_Query with a custom product type and a date range

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, membership

I have to change the product price (only in single product page) depending on orders made in a date range, and if user has a membership.
This is fine, but the problems is that something fails when I use **WC_Order_Query** inside the **woocommerce_get_price_html** filter

The problem is using the WC_Order_Query inside filter, because when I comment it then works. What can I use for that query? Or I have to change of filter, hook?

```
function change_price( $price ) {   
    global $product;

    if($product->get_type() != "lottery") return $price;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $membresias = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships($user_id); // Get the memberships of user, returning an array

    if(!$membresias) return;

    foreach ($membresias as $value) {
        if ($value->status == "wcm-free_trial" || $value->status == "wcm-active") {
            $currentDayOfWeek = date("N");

            $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.(intval($currentDayOfWeek )-1).' days'));
            $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.(7 - intval($currentDayOfWeek )).' days'));


            $query = new WC_Order_Query(
                array(
                    'limit' => 10,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'return' => 'ids',
                    'customer_id' => $user_id,
                    'date_paid' => $start."...".$end, //'2018-02-01...2018-02-28',
                    'meta_key' => '_lottery',
                )
            );

            $orders = $query->get_orders(); // If I comment this page loads well.

        /* Also fails
        $orders = wc_get_orders(
            array(
                'limit' => 10,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'return' => 'ids',
                'customer_id' => $user_id,
                'date_paid' => $start."...".$end,  //'2018-02-01...2018-02-28',
                'meta_key' => '_lottery',
            )
        );
        */

            $sorteosJugadosCount = 0;
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $order = wc_get_order($order);

                foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {
                    $product = $item_data->get_product();
                    $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity
                    $sorteosJugadosCount += $item_quantity; 
                }
            }   

            if ( $sorteosJugadosCount < 7 )
                return "0€ (Free lottery)";

        }
    }

    return $price;
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_price_display', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What fails is `'meta_key' => '_lottery'`.
>
> **Why?**
> Because you are querying **Orders** but **NOT products** meta data *(order items)*. 
> As "lottery" is a custom product type that has nothing to do with the order meta data, it fails. 
>  **The `WC_Order_Query` is limited.**

You can make a more complex SQL query using **WPDB** in your code, calling `global $wpdb;` obbject, where you will be able to target specific product types in order items.

So the following query will output an array of orders IDs, based on "date paid" range and order item custom product type "lottery". It will replace in your code the `WC_Order_Query`:

```
global $wpdb;

$product_type = 'lottery'; // <== The product type to target

// Dates
$currentDayOfWeek = date("N");
$time_start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.(intval($currentDayOfWeek )-1).' days')));
$time_end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.(7 - intval($currentDayOfWeek )).' days')));

// The SQL query
$order_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT DISTINCT pm.post_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON pm.post_id = woi.order_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr ON woim.meta_value = tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE pm.meta_key LIKE '_date_paid'
    AND pm.meta_value BETWEEN '$time_start' AND '$time_end'
    AND woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
    AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
    AND tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_type'
    AND t.slug LIKE '$product_type'
    ORDER BY pm.meta_value DESC
" );

// Raw output display (testing)
echo '<pre>'; print_r($order_ids); echo '</pre>';
```

This code is tested with normal woocommerce product types as "simple" for example and works. So it should works with your custom product type 'lottery'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but you're not understanding the problem. I'm not querying product. I'm querying **ORDERS**. Why? Because I need to see if the current user has order some products in that date range, and that's why I'm doing it with orders. As I said, that part of the code is perfect. That gives me the correct return. The problem is that I don't know specifically if it's ok to use **WC_Order_Query** inside the *woocommerce_get_price_html* filter. Why? Well because using it breaks me some links asociated with others products.

Comment: I'll try your code to see if using mysql directly not catch the errors. Thanks!

Comment: @ManfredMarcano I know that you are querying Orders **as `WC_Order_Query` is for orders**… **But then what is `'meta_key' => '_lottery',` ??** … For me is not possible to guess that and you should better explain things in your question if you want really to be helped.